# Split string based on symbols $$ and && to access data in Swift

Tags: swift, string

I have a string which has Id and presentation name. String format is $$Id&&presentationName

**$$5955&&Presentation Name1 [CLONE]$$7460&&Presentation Name2 $$7473&&Presentation Name3$$7626&&Presentation Name4 [CLONE]$$7460&&Presentation Name5$$7123&&Presentation Name6**

I want to split string into two array with Id and presentation name based on symbols $$ and &&. I'm new to iOS please help.

Expected Output: **arrayID = [5955, 7460, 7473, 7626, 7460, 7123]**

**arrayPresentationNames = ["Presentation Name1 [CLONE]", "Presentation Name2", "Presentation Name3", "Presentation Name5", "Presentation Name5", "Presentation Name6"]**

I have tried like below but not succeeded.

```
    let separators = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "&&")
    var fullStr: String = "$$3232&&presentation name";
    var words = fullStr.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(separators)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [components](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1413214-components) method to split your string.

Step 1: Split it by the "**$$**" separator, which will give you an array of strings. An instance element in that array will look something like this "**7460&&Presentation Name2**".

Step 2: Split that array again, now by the "**&&**" separator, which gives you the ["7460", "Presentation Name2"] array.

Step 3: From that array, you need to extract the values and assign them to your arrays.

```
let yourString = "$$5955&&Presentation Name1 [CLONE]$$7460&&Presentation Name2 $$7473&&Presentation Name3$$7626&&Presentation Name4 [CLONE]$$7460&&Presentation Name5$$7123&&Presentation Name6"
var arrayPresentationNames: [String] = []
var arrayID: [String] = []

// Step 1 - Separate the string by the "$$"
yourString.components(separatedBy: "$$").forEach({ element in
    // Step 2 - Separate the string by the "&&"
    let splitedComponent = element.components(separatedBy: "&&")
    if let presentationName = splitedComponent.first, !presentationName.isEmpty {
        // Step 3/1 - Extract the presentation name
        arrayPresentationNames.append(presentationName)
    }
    if splitedComponent.count > 1 {
        // Step 3/2 - Extract the id
        arrayID.append(splitedComponent[1])
    }
})
print(arrayPresentationNames) // Prints your presentation names
print(arrayID) // Prints your id's
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution which parses the string into a custom struct with Regular Expression

```
struct Presentation {
    let id : Int
    let name : String
}

let string = "$$5955&&Presentation Name1 [CLONE]$$7460&&Presentation Name2 $$7473&&Presentation Name3$$7626&&Presentation Name4 [CLONE]$$7460&&Presentation Name5$$7123&&Presentation Name6"

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\$\\$(\\d+)&&([^\\$]+)")
let matches = regex.matches(in: string, range: NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string))
let presentations = matches.map { match -> Presentation in
    let numberRange = Range(match.range(at: 1), in: string)!
    let nameRange = Range(match.range(at: 2), in: string)!
    return Presentation(id: Int(string[numberRange])!, name: String(string[nameRange]))
}

print(presentations)
```

Comment: Nice solution, sure beats mine. I had to look up NSRegularExpression.

Answer (score 0):

Using functional programming you can obtain the solution to this problem by first removing the ampersands, then using a flatmap to remove the dollar signs. The provided function would work with any two sets of characters and returns a tuple with the values you are seeking.

```
func removeUnwantedCharacters(remove firstValue:String, and secondValue: String, from string : String) -> (ids:[Int],names:[String]){

    let removeFirstValue = string.components(separatedBy: firstValue)
    let removeAmpersand = removeFirstValue.flatMap { (item) -> [String] in
        item.components(separatedBy: secondValue)
    }

    var presentationNames : [String] = []

    let id = removeAmpersand.compactMap { item -> Int? in

        if Int(item) != nil {
            return Int(item)
        }else{
            if item != "" {
                presentationNames.append(item)
            }
            return nil
        }
    }

    return (id,presentationNames)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = "$$5955&&Presentation Name1 [CLONE]$$7460&&Presentation Name2 $$7473&&Presentation Name3$$7626&&Presentation Name4 [CLONE]$$7460&&Presentation Name5$$7123&&Presentation Name6"

let splits = str.components(separatedBy: "$$").dropFirst().map { $0.components(separatedBy: "&&") }
let arrayID = splits.map { $0.first }
let arrayPresentationNames = splits.map { $0.last }

print(splits)                   // [["5955", "Presentation Name1 [CLONE]"], ["7460", "Presentation Name2 "]...]
print(arrayID)                  // ["5955", "7460"...]
print(arrayPresentationNames)   // ["Presentation Name1 [CLONE]", "Presentation Name2 "...]
```